# Printing of structured objects with correct indentations using streams in C++

Tags: c++, stream

I would like to write the `<<` operators for my classes, which in general contain some structured data. One of the easiest examples is a class containing a list of matrices, e.g.

```
stuct MyClass
{
  std::vector<Matrix> m;
}
```

assume that the Matrix class can print itself (using multiple lines), and that we don't control this class. Now I would like to get the following output:

```
A(0)=[a b
      c d]
A(1)=[e f
      g h]
```

and that the `Matrix` class itself outputs:

```
[a b
 c d]
```

how can configure/change the stream or do something completely different to make it work, i.e. to make the stream output a given number of spaces after every `std::endl`?

Comment: I think you'd have to create your own stream wrapper class, wrap the input stream inside your `operator>>` and use the wrapper to output the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the first real use I made of filtering
streambuf's.  Given something like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest,
                          std::vector<Matrix> const& object );

class MyClass
{
    std::vector<Matrix> m;
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, MyClass const& object )
{
    //  ...
    {
        //  Scope to control lifetime of the IndentingStreambuf...
        //  Could be (probably should be) in a separate function.
        IndentingStreambuf indent( dest )
        dest << m;
    }
    //  ...
}
```

Where:

```
class IndentingStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    std::ostream*   myOwner;
    bool            myIsAtStartOfLine;

protected:
    int overflow( int ch )
    {
        if ( myIsAtStartOfLine && ch != EOF && ch != '\n' ) {
            myDest->sputn( "    ", 4 );
        }
        myIsAtStartOfLine = ch == '\n';
        return myDest->sputc( ch );
    }

public:
    IndentingStreambuf( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myOwner( NULL )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
    {
    }
    IndentingStreambuf( std::ostream& dest )
        : myDest( dest.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &dest )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
    {
        myOwner->rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~IndentingStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != NULL ) {
            myOwner->rdbuf( myDest );
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT:

I just read your desired output in a little more detail.  The
same basic `IndentingStreambuf` works, but

1. you'll have to adapt it to support an arbitrary indent (as
   argument to the constructor),
2. initialize `myIsAtStartOfLine` to `false`, and
3. call it after having output `A(i) = [`.

And of course, define `operator<<` for `Matrix` appropriately.

Alternatively, you could just use `std::ios_base::xalloc` to
obtain a place where you could tell the `operator<<` for
`Matrix` about the indent.  Something along the lines of:

```
static long& getMatrixIndent( std::ostream& dest )
{
    static int ourIndex = std::ostream::xalloc();
    return dest.iword( ourIndex );
}

class indent
{
    int myIndent;
public:
    indent( int n ) : myIndent( n ) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest,
                                     indent const& manip )
    {
        getMatrixIndent( dest ) = myIndent;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Matrix const& object )
{
    int indent = getMatrixIndent( dest );
    //  ...
}
```

This is considerably less flexible than a filtering streambuf.
In particular, it can't be made to work for types where you
don't control the implementation of `operator<<`.  But it's
simple, and also useful at times.

(I'd argue, in fact, that anyone using C++ should be familiar
with both techniques.  But I'm not aware of any tutorial text
which even mentions them.  And in a world where a large number
of C++ users are still writing `while ( ! file.eof() )`, it's
probably too much to ask for.)

Comment: I will give it a go! Would it work to nest these? E.g. if my Matrix class decides to use your `IndentingStreambuf` on the stream (already wrapped in one of these), is it going to add all the indentations needed (i.e. the original+the ones from Matrix class)?

Comment: I got this compiler error when I tried to use it as you showed: `/home/ga1009/PhD/cpp/pmi/cpp/src/baumestimates.h:40:5: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘IndentingStreambuf(12u, (* & os)) << BaumEstimates<N, M, K>::distParams() const [with int N = 2; int M = 1; int K = 1]().boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*<std::vector<DistParams<1> > >()’`

Comment: @Grzenio They nest fine.  On the other hand, my example of how to use it is completely wrong; I don't know what I was thinking of.  I've edited it to fix it.  (And while I'm at it: if you're going to try it, you should probably also try to understand it.  Which means learning about streambuf, and its role in C++ IO.)